# CodeIgniter + Nginx + Other files in /var/www

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, nginx

I have one CodeIgniter project in /var/www. We will call this project proj. So I have a large number of files in /var/www and a CodeIgniter project in /var/www/proj. I am in desperate need of a Nginx configuration that will support this. Should I just do a virtual host? For example: /var/www/somewebsite.com/ and /var/www/proj.somewebsite.com/. Could you supply a working Nginx + CodeIgniter configuration that supports this?

I currently am not using a domain. I am simply on a VPS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes. You have to use virtual hosts, or create server to listen od different ports othrwise how it will server know which location to serve?? unless you mean somethign like `localhost/myporject1/` and `localhost2/myproject2`? then just setup the server to point to root `/var/www` and adjust path in fastcgi for  CI

```
server {
        listen 80; 
        server_name localhost;
        root  /var/www/;


        location ~ /\. {
               deny all;
        }

         #you codigniter project 
        location /yourcodigniterproject {
                index index.html index.php;
                try_files /cache$uri @web;

        }
        #your other project (if usign php replicate the top with difrent directives)
        location /yourotherproject {
                index index.html index.php;
                try_files /cache$uri $uri

        }

        location @web {
                client_max_body_size 10M;
                expires 0;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/yourcodigniterproject/index.php;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

But as said, create virtual hosts  much easier to maintain. create entry (assuming you are suing linux) for each one in `sites-available` and add then remove them as you go with `ln -s` `in`sites-enabled`

I have  configuration like that. One Virtual Server has a site codeignoter setting , the other one is just plain static website, one for phpmyadmin,etc...